# How to write to a file over the network

Tags: linux, bash

I have two ubuntu linux boxes: I'm in bash on one machine running some battery of tests (storage, memory, etc.). Now, I want to test writing to a file over the network to the other linux box. Any idea of the command to write to a file across the network (behind the same router)? I could easily ssh into the second machine, but I want to send data across the network, writing to a file at the root or some particular directory. Thanks!

Comment: "*the* command"? There are many ways to transfer files. Also, do you care how fast the destination machine can write to its disk? Does that matter?

Comment: This question would be better served on superuser.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use scp (Secure copy) or rsync (Remote Sync).

From the command line type

```
scp file_to_copy user@remote_linx:/tmp/copy_of_file
```

Comment: your answer is exactly not what he wanted

Answer (score 3):

[SCP!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy)

Comment: from the command line ... I'm using putty. I don't want to use winscp.

Comment: scp isn't WinSCP, but for what it's worth, I would recommend rsync through an SSH tunnel over scp.

Comment: sorry, I was quick on the draw ... now I know. Thanks.

Comment: I edited my description above. I want to write to an existing file over the network.